# How to setup CUPS to keep a log of how many pages I printed?

Tags: logging, printing, cups

i have a Debian computer setup with CUPS. I need to record how many pages I'm printing, for work. Is there a way to set up CUPS to store a log each time I print, with the quantity of pages printed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so for example by using tea4cups. It is called accounting, for a example config see the debian wiki: https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSTea4CUPS#Printer_Accounting